# Port number that SQL database project uses for deploying database

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, database-connection, database-deployment

I want to know which port number uses a dbproj(Database Project) in visual studio 2010 to deploy a database in a remote server or how can I find that info
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the connection string.  A default connection uses 1433, but you can specify a different port number by using a comma after the host name.